# Cannot read property 'previewTemplate' of undefined dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, filereader, dropzone.js

I use DropzoneJs is for uploading file, everything works fine, but if I want to add files from clipboard to drop zone I have to use FileReader. is when I user FileReader. guess I get following error "Cannot read property 'previewTemplate' of undefined"

my dropzone code

```
Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm = {
maxFiles: 9999,
url: "ajax/uploader.aspx",
init: function () {
    this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function (data) {
        var res = eval('(' + data.xhr.responseText + ')');
    });
    this.on("addedfile", function (file) {
        var removeButton = Dropzone.createElement("<button>Remove file</button>");
        var _this = this;
        removeButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            _this.removeFile(file);
        });
        file.previewElement.appendChild(removeButton);
    });

    this.on("complete", function (file) {
        if (file.name.indexOf(".jpg") > -1) {
            uploadDoneimg("img", file);
        } else if (file.name.indexOf(".png") > -1) {
              else
                    {
                        ShowMessage('e', "Error p2i Convert !");
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    });


    this.on("drop", function (file) {
        //  alert("drop : " + file.name);
    });


  }
};


FileReaderJS.setupClipboard(document.body, {
    accept: {
        'image/*': 'DataURL'
    },
    on: {
        load: function (e, cfile) {           
            $(Dropzone).addfile(cfile);
        }
    }
});
```

this combination happend in following link

https://www.bitpixr.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is by definition of Drop Zone. is when you want to add files from clipboard and pass the file to drop zone you have to initialize DropZone. is in dynamic way then every thing will work fine

oh don't forget to set auto discover false :)

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

var myDropZone = new Dropzone("div#dropzoneForm", {url:''});

FileReaderJS.setupClipboard(document.body, {
    accept: {
        'image/*': 'DataURL'
    },
    on: {
        load: function (e, cfile) {           
            $(Dropzone).addfile(cfile);
        }
    }
});
```